# Using mail_to with a block (mail_to ... do)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, mailto

I would like to do the following to insert a styled `mail_to`:

```
<%= mail_to @colleague.email do %>
  <span class="email" id="colleague_40"> Reply by Email </span>
<% end %>
```

The RoR docs aren't specific on the topic of `mail_to` blocks but the above code doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do a block in conjunction with `mail_to`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<% mail_content = capture do %>
    <span class="email" id="colleague_40"> Reply by Email </span>
<% end %>

<%= mail_to @colleague.email, mail_content %>
```